# Django query Create - the field is determined by a string

Tags: django

I'm try create a object with django with string:

my model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    field_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Code for Create:

```
 real_field = "field_"+str(level)
 example = Example(
                user_id=user_id,
                real_field=value_1,
                ......
 )
 example.save()
```

how create this..please thanks ..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 real_field = "field_"+str(level)
 example = Example(
                user_id=user_id,
                ......
 )
example.setattr(real_field,value_1)
example.save()
```

setattr is what you look for,

or

```
 data = {}
 data["field_"+str(level)] = value1
 example = Example(
                user_id=user_id,
                ......,
                **data
 )
 example.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dict to the model constructor function:

```
example = Example(**{
                'user_id': user_id,
                real_field: value_1,
                ......
 })
 example.save()
```